# How to properly store raster data in GRIB format

Tags: geotiff-tiff, grib, grib-2, storage

I have some raster data stored as individual uncompressed `geotiff` files (one file per time step) that I would like to store in a more compact way. I have decided to try different formats and see which one yields the best results, but the poor performance of GRIB surprised me.

Currently, I am using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/index.html) to do the conversion like so:

```
gdal_translate xxxxx.tiff xxxxx.grib -of GRIB
```

But the resulting file is almost the same size as the original, it goes from 28.4 KB to 28.2 KB! Am I doing something wrong? Isn't the GRIB format supposed to have compression as a high priority?

I have tried using the [ecCodes API](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC) directly but found out that it only supports reading information from a GRIB file or modifying existing GRIB messages, but not writing one from scratch. Even python packages that are based on this API like `cfgrib` or `pygrib` explicitly say that they don't support writing GRIB files.

How does one store data in a GRIB file if the data is in another format? Is there any library/package that supports that? What is the standard way of storing raster data using GRIB format?

Comment: I would experiment with the DATA_ENCODING options https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/grib.html

Comment: With eccodes, you can clone an existing GRIB message, and overwrite any information you want. You can create a template with "stable" informations (grid definition, ...) and clone it for each message you want to write.

Comment: Hmm... I see, is this the only workflow available? What if I just have a bunch of data I want to store in a georeferenced way? I recently learned about the GRIB format and perhaps it is not what I need, too much metadata.